# Is there a planar 4-regular graph that is 3-acyclic colourable?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-colouring

A colouring is said to be an acyclic colouring if there is no bicoloured cycle (i.e each cycle gets at least 3 colours).

Burstein proved that 4-regular graphs are 5-acyclic colourable. **It seems to me that no planar 4-regular graph is 3-acyclic colourable** (might be even true for 4-regular graphs in general).

Am I wrong?
Is this already studied? (I admit I couldn't find any).

Comment: By the way, is there an English translation of Burstein's paper? (original is in Russian)

Comment: So your question is whether there is a 4-regular (planar) graph such that we can PROPERLY 3-color its VERTICES such that every cycles gets all 3 colors.

Comment: @domotorp Exactly

Comment: It's possible to 3-color the rhombicuboctahedron so that every face has all three colors. But that doesn't answer your question because there might be non-face cycles that are still only 2-colored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can prove that no 4-regular graphs are 3-acyclic colorable.

Consider a 4-regular graph with a 3-coloring. If we call the colors $a, b, c$, then one of the three subgraphs generated by restricting to either $a$ and $b$ colored vertices, $a$ and $c$ vcertices, or $b$ and $c$ vertices must have as many edges as vertices. But all graphs with as many edges as vertices contain a cycle, so the coloring is not acyclic.

Let the graph have $k$ vertices. The graph must have $2k$ edges, because it is 4-regular. Let the number of $a$ colored vertices be $k_a$, and similarly for $k_b$ and $k_c$. Call $e_{ab}$ the number of edges between $a$ and $b$ colored vertices, and the same for $e_{ac}$ and $e_{bc}$. If we assume that none of the restricted graphs have as many edges as vertices, we must have
$$
e_{ab} < k_a + k_b \\
e_{ac} < k_a + k_c \\
e_{bc} < k_b + k_c \\
$$
Summing over all edges, we find that $e_{ab} + e_{ac} + e_{bc} < 2(k_a + k_b + k_c)$, and so $e < 2k$. But this contradicts the fact that 4-regular graphs have twice as many edges as vertices, mentioned above. Thus, the assumption is false, and some color-restricted subgraph has as many edges as vertices, and hence has a cycle.

Comment: Great. Similarly, we can prove that 6-regular graphs are not 4-acyclic colourable.

Comment: In general, $2k$-regular graphs are not $(k+1)$-acyclic colourable.

Comment: I would like to cite this answer (in the usual way). How should I give your name: Is it Issac G. ? (full name would be preferable).

Comment: @CyriacAntony My name is Isaac Grosof.

Comment: Sorry, earlier I couldn't find it in the literature. But, the lower bound given by your answer (i.e. $\chi_a(G)\geq (d+3)/2$) is also a direct consequence of Proposition 1 in Fertin et al., [Acyclic and $k$-distance coloring of the grid](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(03)00232-1). But, your proof is more beautiful.